# right use of "if clauses" in batch file. OS windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I don't know if i use my if clauses in my batch file right, because something wont work. I would be greatful for any help. My code looks like this:

```
if ( 
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release gtr 4 
)   
(
IMEI5.bat
)else(
f.txt
)
```

I'm useing it like that because I found this example

```
If (condition) (command1) Else (command2)
```

So the

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
```

gets me something like 4.4.3 or 5.5.3
I just want to determine if its version 4 or 5 if its 5 or greater i would like to execute the IMEI5.bat else i want to open a text file.
Thank you for your help in advance. :)

Comment: Does this command `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release` show just a number on the console?

Comment: yes in form of 4.4.3 or 5.1.5 or so just those 3 numbers with dots

Comment: Why did you delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964788/how-to-add-version-control-to-android-studio? It could have helped other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=." %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release') do (
   if %%a EQU 4 notepad "f.txt"
   if %%a GEQ 5 call IMEI5.bat
)   
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release` returns a value, if it does, make sure the value it being set to a variable.
The basic of the if-else condition in batch is:

```
if %VALUE% gtr SOME_VALUE (
    DO_SOMETHING
) else (
    DO_SOMETHING
)
```

Comment: could you make a suggestion how to stall the adb shell ... in a variable? sorry i am very bad in scripting. 
PS: thank you for your answer

Comment: I'm not so sure about this, but you can try this: `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cmd /c adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release') do set "version_var=%%a"`, tell me if it's not working

Comment: allready got it with
set var1=adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release

but thank you for your help very nice

Comment: @Foster Wow, didn't expect it will work with just as simple as `set ... = ...` ! Thanks for your "mark as answer" .

Comment: @darkfang  It doesn't work like that.  He's confused himself or fibbing. :)

Comment: @foxidrive Well it worked only for command %var% so you got the number. But I managed it like this 
for /f %%i in ('adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release') do set VAR=%%i
set vdb=%VAR:~0,1%

if %vdb% gtr 4 (
IMEI5.bat

) 


f.txt

thank you all for your help